# Select C# timeout

Tags: c#, select

I have the following problem: I am waiting on select for a socket.

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();    
a.Add(Socket1);   
print_time_before  
Select(a, null, null, 8000000);  
print_time_after
```

1. I can see that the time that between the printing is not 8 seconds although no other application wrote to that socket. What is wrong ?
2. ia a contains the socket it means that there is nothing to read or that there is ?

Comment: What is the unit type of the last parameter in the Select()? Usually it's milliseconds and 8000000ms isn't 8 seconds

Comment: @spots I suspect it's `Socket.Select`; public static void Select(
 IList checkRead,
 IList checkWrite,
 IList checkError,
 int microSeconds
)

Comment: It sais it microseconds, which means that 1 million is a second

Answer (score 0):

It's in the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select(v=vs.100).aspx):

> If you are in a listening state, readability means that a call to Accept will succeed without blocking. If you have already accepted the connection, readability means that data is available for reading. In these cases, all receive operations will succeed without blocking. Readability can also indicate whether the remote Socket has shut down the connection; in that case a call to Receive will return immediately, with zero bytes returned.
>
> Select returns when at least one of the sockets of interest (the sockets in the checkRead, checkWrite, and checkError lists) meets its specified criteria, or the microSeconds parameter is exceeded, whichever comes first. Setting microSeconds to -1 specifies an infinite time-out.

So, what is the state of the socket?

Comment: The socket is in the list also after the select. 
nothing was recieved on the socket and it walk up before time out

Comment: @BigLeonardo I asked what the state of the selected socket is. Is it closed? Is it listening and is there a client ready to Accept()?